# how to get span element by id?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Actually i create a popup with close icon and i try to close popup form using span method. I want to get span element value by element id.

```
       <script>
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML....

Comment: How many elements in your source code have the class name "close"?

Comment: why did not use document.getElementById?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `getElementByTagName` or `getElementById` instead of by the class.

Alternatively, try to add the attribute `onclick` directly in the DOM on the wanted span element, and then call a function which does what you want.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the `.onclick` is coming from but add events in js that are not inline in an html element is different. For instance you wouldn't say

```
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

you would say

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
});
```

if you were using jQuery you could do something like

```
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
});
```

or

```
$('#myBtn').on('click', function() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
});
```

but that just comes down to preference as you can also add the event to the document and specify the target

```
$(document).on('click', '#myBtn', function() {
    modal.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Comment: so then you would go with what I put in the second code block to hook up an event to it. the one with `.addEventListener`